# DatabaseHandler declaration

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there any difference between these two statements ??

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
DatabaseHandler dbs ;
```

Answer (score 0):

First statement was declared the DatabaseHandler object as db and it initiated by new keyword while the second statement was just declared the DatabaseHandler object as dbs.

Check out this for more detail about declaration, initiated etc from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)